# How to apply custom theme to entire application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply a custom theme to my React app. I have tried to follow the instructions on the [Material docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/) and have come up with the following:

Here is my `index.js` which I just can't appear to get the `NavBar` / `AppBar` or any other component to pickup these theme changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'typeface-roboto';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
     primary: {
        light: '#f44336',
        main: 'rgb(23, 105, 170)',
        dark: '#000'
     },
     secondary: {
       light: '#f44336',
       main: '#f44336',
     },
  },
  typography: { 
     useNextVariants: true
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavBar color="primary" />
      //<NavBar /> does not work either
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Please show the code for `NavBar`. It would also be helpful for you to provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NavBar` component isn't a MaterialUI Component, it's just a React component.

You'll need to pass that `color` down as a prop and then use it in the `NavBar` component's MUI components.

Here's an example:

```
...
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const NavBar = ({ color }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <AppBar color={color}>
      ...
      <Button color={color} /> // This is an MUI component
      ...
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```